# Closure::bindTo how it's work?

Tags: php, oop, closures

**For example, i have some code:**

```
class A
{
    private $value = 100;
}
$a = new A;
$closure = function(){echo $this->value;};
$binding = $closure->bindTo($a,"A"); /// tag
$binding();
```

**I have some questions:**

1. When we write in the line marked `tag` second argument as an "A", does it mean that the execution context is inside an anonymous function is the same as inside the class "A"?
2. If instead of "A" write, "static" in the context of an anonymous function which will be executed?
3. If we write in the second argument "static", then is it something associated with the LSB?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation already answer these?

Comment: I have not seen this in the documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me help you interpret the manual at http://php.net/Closure.bindTo

> `newscope`
>
> The class scope to which associate the closure is to be associated, or 'static' to keep the current one. If an object is given, the type of the object will be used instead. **This determines the visibility of protected and private methods of the bound object.**

So, to answer your first question, yes, it means the code is interpreted like it were a method of the `A` class.

If the context were `"static"` (second question), then, when executing you get:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property A::$value in php shell code on line 1

That's because `"static"` will *keep the current [scope]* (i.e. the scope which the Closure has been set to last; e.g. if it's bound to `A`, it will remain bound to `A`). In this case, it was simply unscoped and now still is unscoped; it doesn't magically behave like it were part of `A` class (or any of the classes extending it) and thus does not have access to the protected or private properties.

Regarding the third question, `"static"` here is just preserving the currently set scope. It has no further meaning. The only reason for `"static"` as identifier is that no class may be named `static` (thus it won't clash with any possible class name).

I.e. (using `$closure` from your initial example):

```
$binding = $closure->bindTo($a, "A"); // scope is now A class
$second_binding = $binding->bindTo($a, "static"); // scope is still A class
$second_binding(); // works fine, no access issues
```

Comment: hmm, you aren't right, your code is not right: `$binding = $closure->bindTo($a, "A"); // scope is now A class
$binding = $closure->bindTo($a, "static"); // scope is not still A class
$binding(); // error with access issues`

Comment: Can u say me about third question:"keyword `static` has relation to LSB"?

Comment: About second question: "which is current scope?". Current scope is it which find in anonymous function?

Comment: @MaximPro Yeah, copy paste failure, I meant to bind on the already bound Closure, sorry

Comment: @MaximPro _static_ has no further meaning. It's simply preserving the binding. Not related to LSB. — Also clarified "current scope".

Comment: Sorry for repeat question but, "which is current scope?". Current scope is it which find in anonymous function?

Comment: @MaximPro Not sure what your understanding problem is? Initial scope is inherited by the place where the Closure has been defined. If this is inside a method of a class A, then the scope is A. If inside a method of a class B, then scope is B. If outside of a class, then it's unscoped. Now, if we bindTo(), the scope of the new closure is the given scope (or the old one if `static`).

Comment: Can u agree with my expression? "Current scope is it which find in anonymous function(when second arg = "static")"? Yes or not?

Comment: @MaximPro I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can figure the current scope via `$r = (new ReflectionFunction($the_closure))->getClosureScopeClass(); if ($r) { print $r->getName(); } else { print "<unbound/static>"; }` … and draw your own conclusions from that.

Comment: @MaximPro ah yeah, `Closure` is the default scope (which is defacto the same as unscope as no class may inherit from Closure and Closure has no protected or private methods and properties).

Comment: @MaximPro sure. It's scope is _Closure_, thus anon function.

Comment: As soon as you answer my questions, I will gladly accept your answer

Comment: @MaximPro var_dump/print_r just outputs the object with its complete state, independently from scope. Binding does not influence this.

Comment: And last group questions, and i really after this agree your answer. I want to understand. https://repl.it/DrnX/8

Comment: @MaximPro that's right, except for the last point; … you meant that it _is_ scoped to class B?!

Comment: No I'm not mistaken. But it is seems such as construction 'use'. Is not it?

Comment: ah. got it; fine then.

Comment: You agree with all of my statements?